# How to divide group of field with another group of fields in Crystal Reports graphs?

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

I am creating a Crystal Report which consist of a graph. As I am new to this, I might be having problem with a very simple issue.

I have a table which consist of date, actual_rev, hrs_available, etc.

Now what I need in the graph is for each date sum of the actual_rev/ sum of the hrs_available. And this should be done grouping of every single date so that graph shows bar of each date.

In the above example the revenue sums up to 2317.00 and the hours sums up to 15.33 , getting the revenue per hour 151.14, which should be shown in the graph for this date.

Comment: This question featured an attachment or an image via a webmail URL, which is long dead. Since the question doesn't make much sense without it, I am voting to close.